# Cannot groupby pd.Grouper on datetime.time object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I don't understand how to group by considering only the time in a pandas DataFrame.

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

df = (
    pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-01-01 12:10:00', '2018-01-02 12:11:00']})
    .assign(
        date=lambda df: df.date.astype('datetime64').dt.time,
        foo='bar',
    )
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='10T'))
    .agg('count')
)
# throws TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

df = (
    pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-01-01 12:10:00', '2018-01-02 12:11:00']})
    .assign(
        date=lambda df: df.date.astype('datetime64'),
        foo='bar',
    )
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='10T'))
    .agg('count')
)
```

works but does take the day into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time` in pandas is python object, so not working with `Grouper`. Possible solution is select times with split and convert to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) or convert to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) - get same dates, because `datetime` always contain `date`:

```
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-01-01 12:10:00', '2018-01-02 12:11:00']})
    .assign(date=lambda df: pd.to_timedelta(df.date.str.split().str[1]))
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='10T'))
    .size()
)
print (df)

date
12:10:00    2
Freq: 10T, dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-01-01 12:10:00', '2018-01-02 12:11:00']})
    .assign(date=lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df.date.str.split().str[1]))
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='10T'))
    .size()
)
print (df)

date
2019-01-15 12:10:00    2
Freq: 10T, dtype: int64
```

If input column have `datetime` dtype, use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert to strings:

```
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01 12:10:00', '2018-01-02 12:11:00'])})
    .assign(date=lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df.date.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='10T'))
    .size()
)
print (df)
date
2019-01-15 12:10:00    2
Freq: 10T, dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01 12:10:00', '2018-01-02 12:11:00'])})
    .assign(date=lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df.date.dt.time.astype(str)))
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='10T'))
    .size()
)
print (df)
date
2019-01-15 12:10:00    2
Freq: 10T, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks I would go with `pd.to_timedelta(df.date.astype('datetime64').dt.time.astype(str))` then because it does not add fake day. I am surprised anyway it is necessary to use `str` type in between for this basic requirement

Comment: Awesome detailed examples! +1